# Cell should not highlight automatically when view loads

Tags: swift, tvos

I am working on TVOS. I have used UICollectionView. When view loads, the first cell is automatically highlighted. As per the requirement, cell should not highlight automatically.

```
// MARK: UIFocusEnvironment
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
        if self.isFocused {
            if !self.isList {
                self.titleLabel.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.titleLabel.isHidden = false
            }
            self.focusImageView.alpha = 0
            self.favoriteView.alpha = 0
            self.topLabelConstraint.constant = 55
            self.bottomLabelConstraint.constant = -20
            self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 30)
            self.loadFocusImage()
        } else {
            if !self.isList {
                self.titleLabel.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.titleLabel.isHidden = false
            }
            self.focusImageView.image = nil
            //self.titleLabel.text =
            self.focusImageView.alpha = 0
            self.imgView.alpha = 1.0
            self.favoriteView.alpha = 1.0
            self.topLabelConstraint.constant = 20
            self.bottomLabelConstraint.constant = 15
            self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 22.0)
        }

    }, completion: {})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here I got my answer. 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TVManager.shared.isSelected = false
    }

    // MARK: UIFocusEnvironment
        override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({
                if self.isFocused {
                    if !self.isList {
                        self.titleLabel.isHidden = true
                    } else {
                        self.titleLabel.isHidden = false
                    }
                    if TVManager.shared.isSelected {
                        self.focusImageView.alpha = 0
                                       self.favoriteView.alpha = 0
                                       self.topLabelConstraint.constant = 55
                                       self.bottomLabelConstraint.constant = -20
                                       self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 30)
                                       self.loadFocusImage()
                    } else {
                        self.focusImageView.image = nil
                        //self.titleLabel.text =
                        self.focusImageView.alpha = 0
                        self.imgView.alpha = 1.0
                        self.favoriteView.alpha = 1.0
                        self.topLabelConstraint.constant = 20
                        self.bottomLabelConstraint.constant = 15
                        self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 22.0)
                        TVManager.shared.isSelected = true
                    }

                } else {
                    if !self.isList {
                        self.titleLabel.isHidden = true
                    } else {
                        self.titleLabel.isHidden = false
                    }
                    self.focusImageView.image = nil
                    //self.titleLabel.text =
                    self.focusImageView.alpha = 0
                    self.imgView.alpha = 1.0
                    self.favoriteView.alpha = 1.0
                    self.topLabelConstraint.constant = 20
                    self.bottomLabelConstraint.constant = 15
                    self.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 22.0)
                }

            }, completion: {})
        }
```